# How does Linux find devices on x86 IO address bus at boot?

Tags: linux, x86, bios

So devices are arranged on x86 device bus with unique ranges somehow. AFAIK, in the old days if you were using DOS or some real mode OS you could configure these ranges through the BIOS. Device also had conventional addresses. [This site show a Table - Common Hex Addresses](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=107). But Linux doesn't use the BIOS. I can't believe that these addresses are hard coded into any OS including Linux anymore. Modern Linux kernel surely must somehow dynamically discovering devices on this address bus and there address ranges. But how?!

Comment: What makes you think Linux doesn't use the BIOS? It's true that Linux is less dependent on the BIOS than some other OS kernels, preferring to work directly with hardware, rather than using the BIOS (which is unfortunately far too often not kept up to date to handle all modern hardware), but I think "doesn't use the BIOS" is a pretty significant overstatement...

Comment: @twalberg How does it use the BIOS? Can you point to any case where it does? I would be interested to know.

Comment: Getting initial hardware information during boot; much of the ACPI subsystem, including suspend/resume handling, power management, etc. Device hotplug handling in some cases, depending on what kind of attachment (USB vs. PCI vs memory or CPU or ...). It's more accurate to say that Linux does not solely rely on the BIOS, but there are still quite a few points where it must interact with it.

Comment: @twalberg Is ACPI considered BIOS in the conventional sense? I'm not really sure what ACPI is yet, but the way I thought of "BIOS" was real mode routines like what DOS uses. No?

Comment: Ok, if you think of BIOS as only what it was 20 years ago - character and text input/output routines, disk input/output routines, etc., then it may be fair (but I'm still not entirely sure it's completely correct) to think that Linux doesn't use those bits. But the bits of a computer considered BIOS these days (while no longer strictly a "Basic Input/Output System"), are much more extensive. ACPI is generally considered a part of (or maybe a separate) BIOS, as is the firmware on many addon cards (e.g. PXE BIOS on network cards, or mode-changing/configuration firmware on display adapters...)

Comment: If you want to make a distinction, you can say "BIOS" = legacy 16-bit mode crap, including legacy MBR booting.  The stuff in ROM as a whole is the motherboard *firmware*, and includes ACPI tables, UEFI booting, the bootup config screen, etc.  (People would still often say "BIOS setup", though, and it's not wrong to talk about the whole firmware as the BIOS.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some device addresses are fixed , and "defined" by the platform. Others are dyanamic (programmable) and these are usually set-up by the firmware during boot. It depends if we're talking about system devices or add-on peripherals.

Most devices are found via typical PCI bus scanning, where each device exports its various BARs via registers in PCI config space. These BARs (and thus address ranges) are programmed by the firmware at boot, and can refer to memory or I/O port addresses.

Another means of device discovery is via ACPI tables. The kernel finds the ACPI tables by scanning through a prescribed memory region looking for a marker. These tables are constructed by the firmware at boot.

There is a good deal of information on OSdev.org.

There are a small number of hard-coded addresses in the kernel. You can easily look these up by browsing through the arch/x86 directory. These are addresses that simply do not change because they are part of the platform "definition" (and I use that word loosely). A couple examples include the text-mode VGA memory at B8000 and the BIOS data area at 400.

Linux kernel source code:

- [`arch/x86/pci/direct.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/pci/direct.c?v=3.19) - I/O port `CF8h`/`CFCh` access to PCI config space

Comment: Thank you. Regarding PCI (and other busses), I would assumed once Linux has found the PCI bus in the IO address space it can load a driver to figure out what all the devices on it are. I just assumed that is how it would work(?). It was how to find the PCI bus in the first place that confused me.

Comment: You don't have to "find the PCI bus". PCI config space is architecturally-defined to be accessed via configuration mechanism 1 via I/O ports CF8h and CFCh. From there, you scan for devices on the bus.  But again, this is all probably exposed via the ACPI tables as well.